# Extracting Multiple Strings in a Single Line, Between Two Types of Characters

Tags: text-processing, sed, command-line

I have file consisting of a single line of text. I am trying to obtain the strings between the "#" and "@" symbols and store them as a newline on "Sequence.txt".

For example, I have the input line:

```
#HelloMyName@#IsAdam@#NiceToMeetYou@
```

The expected output should be:

```
HelloMyName
IsAdam
NiceToMeetYou
```

I have tried the command: following line of code:

```
sed 's/.*#\(.*\)@.*/\1/' >> Sequence.txt
```

However, the output is exactly the input:

```
#HelloMyName@#IsAdam@#NiceToMeetYou@
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work with the gnu version of sed ( by default on every linux  )

```
echo -n '#HelloMyName@#IsAdam@#NiceToMeetYou@' | sed 's/#\([^@]*\)@/\1\n/g'
```

give me

```
HelloMyName
IsAdam
NiceToMeetYou
```

On macos

```
echo -n '#HelloMyName@#IsAdam@#NiceToMeetYou@' | sed 's/#\([^@]*\)@/\1\'$'\n''/g'
```

These are examples with echo the same will work files .

```
echo -n '#HelloMyName@#IsAdam@#NiceToMeetYou@'  > input.txt

sed 's/#\([^@]*\)@/\1\n/g' input.txt > sequence.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk (`gawk`), using `FPAT` to define a field as a sequence of non-`#@` characters:

```
$ gawk '{$1=$1} 1' FPAT='[^#@]+' OFS='\n' file >> Sequence.txt
$ 
$ tail Sequence.txt 
HelloMyName
IsAdam
NiceToMeetYou
```

Similar approach, in perl:

```
perl -lpe '$_ = join "\n", /[^#@]+/g' file >> Sequence.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This sequence:

```
[^#]*    # Accept some string of characters that are **not** the start character.
#        # Followed by an start character #
[^@]*    # Followed by an string of **not** ending characters.
@        # Followed by an ending character.
```

Repeated several times would capture (almost) the whole line.

Like this:

```
s/[^#]*#\([^@]\)@/\1\n/g
```

That will  convert the input line into several lines as requested.
The only thing missing is to erase what may remain.

```
sed 's/[^#]*#\([^@]*\)@/\1\n/g;s/\(.*\)\n.*$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumes that # @ # @.... occur in this order.

```
$ perl -lne 'print for /#(.*?)@/g' file
```

Posix Sed:

```
° turn all @ to newlines, guaranteed to not be present.
° Then shave off upto the leading #.
° Thereby uncovering the element to be printed.
```

.

```
$ sed -e '
   y/@/\n/
   s/^[^#]*#//
   P;D
' file
```

Comment: $ perl -lne 'print for /#(.*?)@/g' file works perfectly, even when there are strings before and after the # and @ respectively, thank you so much!